# Identify a websocket from an ExpressJS request

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

How can one use an Express POST request as the basis for a socket.io broadcast (instead of a socket message)?

```
var app    = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io     = require('socket.io')(server);

app.post('/campaigns', function(req, res, next) {
  var campaign = new Campaign(req.body);
  campaign.save(function(err, campaign) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(campaign);

      // how to broadcast a message to everyone
      // except the sender of this POST request?
      io.of('/campaigns').emit('new', campaign);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems much simpler to broadcast to all clients and let the sender ignore the message. They know who they are... ;)

Comment: That might be the only answer. However I wouldn't say it isn't worth solving; you could say the same thing about the socket.broadcast functionality that exists now.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

Each time you establish a connection to server, your `socket` object will have id associated with this connection. Save it on client side in some variable.

Then each time you post a request to server add socket id to query parameters. Upon receiving POST request on server side broadcast the message to all users and socket id  to message. On client side modify on `message` event by adding a logic to skip/hide received message if client's socket id is equal to socket id received as a extra parameter in message.

**Pitfalls**

1. May not work if for some reason after POST request client was disconnected and reconnected to server - in this case upon receiving a message back client will have new socket id that is different from what it had before sending POST request. In that case you will have to come up with some more connection-independent client ID scheme to identify client and use it instead of `socket.id` as identifier. You may try to use sessions.
2. Client will still receive message even if it won't be displayed.
3. Not good to combine client-server "intercommunication" methods and use one from another and vice versa.